# What is the scope of the callback on my vanilla JSONP

Tags: javascript, callback, jsonp, twitch

A little backstory, I'm using the Twitch (game streaming service) api to pull a list of followers from a channel on the site. In order to get around the CORS rules I'm using JSONP. Personally, I prefer to use vanilla javascript over libraries so I learned how to do it from the excellent article over on https://cameronspear.com/blog/exactly-what-is-jsonp/ .

Below is my simplified javascript (the actual code probably isn't extremely necessary, but maybe it'll help to clarify my question afterward):

```
//Function to pull JSONP

function pullJSONP(url) {

    var JSONPInstance = document.createElement('script');
    JSONPInstance.src = url;

    JSONPInstance.onload = function () {
        this.remove();
    };

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.insertBefore(JSONPInstance, null);
} 


//End function to pull JSONP


function storeCurrentFollows(offset) //Function to wrap entire operation
{


    function pullStartSessionFollows(JSONdata) //Callback from JSONP down below
    { 


        function pushNameElements(followEntry) //Function to add names into array
        {

            allSessionFollows.push(followEntry.user.name);

        }

        JSONdata.follows.forEach(pushNameElements); //Iterate through followers

        storeCurrentFollows(offset+100); //Rerun operation, incrementing offset by 100

    }; 

    if(offset > 300){ return }
    else
    {
        //running JSONP function from above, passing in url and setting a callback
        pullJSONP('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + channelName + '/follows?direction=desc&limit=100&offset=' + offset + '&callback=pullStartSessionFollows');

    }


}


storeCurrentFollows(0);
```

So my question is this, whenever I run this operation with the items in this order it returns the error `> Uncaught ReferenceError: pullStartSessionFollows is not defined` in the console. It doesn't work properly unless I move the `pullStartSessionFollows` function up into the global scope. What I don't understand is why it thinks it is undefined even though it is instantiated just before I run the pullJSONP() function. I don't want to move it because then I'll have to pass in my offset to two different functions as well as a few other issues. Any help or insight would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're rolling out your own method you might want to consider using web workers for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't work properly unless I move the pullStartSessionFollows function up into the global scope.

Correct, [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) callbacks must be global functions. It's intrinsic to the way JSONP works.

> What I don't understand is why it thinks it is undefined even though it is instantiated just before I run the pullJSONP() function.

Because that creates the function within the function where you do that (`storeCurrentFollows`), not as a global. But the way JSONP works requires that the function be global.

You can have the `pullStartSessionFollows` function only exist while you have a pending JSONP call, by declaring it as a global variable:

```
var pullStartSessionFollows;
```

...and then assigning to that within `storeCurrentFollows`:

```
pullStartSessionFollows = function() { /* ... */ };
```

You can also remove it when the callback has done its work:

```
pullStartSessionFollows = undefined;
```

---

***Why*** must the callback function be a global? Because the way JSONP works is by adding a script element to the page, as though you had written this in the HTML:

```
<script src="http://example.com/get?callback=pullStartSessionFollows"></script>
```

...and then the response looks like:

```
pullStartSessionFollows({/*...JSON here...*/})
```

That requires that it be a global function.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you! I had a feeling that it had something to do with it requiring a global scope, but for the life of me I couldn't find any documentation specifying such requirements. I can't believe I didn't think to specify a global variable and then reassign it within my function. You've just saved me a ton of headaches, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

The function called as the JSONP callback has to be global (or a property of a global object). The callback expression returned as the response body from a JSONP service is evaluated in the global context.  The server is returning something that looks like

```
pullStartSessionFollows({ ... });
```

Your function is defined inside that other function, so it's not global.

Answer (score 0):

jsonp callback must live within the global javascript scope, since at the time the request finishes, there is no way to determine the original scope of the callback function, that's why it will be executed in the global scope which is pretty much accessible from any scope.